# url limpia en Django 3.x

Tags: django, condiciones, url, django-urls

Muy buena mi gente, me estoy entrando en el mundo de la programación en django y quisiera saber si es posible poder crear url iguales a las que existen en wordpress.

ejemplo

http://pagina.com/hola-mundo

por lo tanto lo primero que debo hacer es validar si ese /hola-mundo viene por la url o no o si no que me direccione a la pagina principal

me explico

```
# Create your views here.
def home_inicio(request):
    if request.GET:
#si viene /hola-mundo , me envié a articulo.html y muestro la data en esa pagina del articulo hola mundo
        data = ...consulta a la base...
        return render(request, "home/articulo.hml", {'data': data})
    else:
#si no viene /hola-mundo redirecciono a pagina principal
        
        return render(request, "home/home.html" , {})
```

se me ocurre un código así, es por eso mi consulta, ¿es factible o no?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es crear rutas por ejemplo ```/home``` o ```/contacto``` si no existe tal ruta te da un error, pero eso lo puedes manera con redirecciones

Comment: tengo creada la /articulo, pero no quiero que se vea esa ruta, solo que se val el dominio y después el nombre el articulo por url, estaba mirando y hay una opción que son los slug, veré si con eso puedo obtener lo que quiero.

Comment: osea lo que quieres es algo como esto ```midominio.com/nombre-del-articulo```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La redirección la defines en el fichero `urls.py`. De hecho lo que te interesa es definir cualquier otra cosa que no sea un artículo **antes** de definir las rutas para los artículos, y éstos mostrarlos a partir de un campo `slug`. Por ejemplo, si tienes páginas además de artículos:

```
from blog.views import articulo_detail #suponiendo que la app se llama blog

urlpatterns = [
    path('paginas/<slug:slug>/', include('paginas.urls'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<slug:slug>/', articulo_detail),
    path('', home_view),
]
```

Espero que sea de ayuda